# exporting properties hide xml

Tags: java, spring, maven

In my maven project I need to read properties which are in other project so I use the resources to export them and read them in my project

```
<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources/config</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.*</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.class</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

this is in the build in the pom.xml inside the project containing the resources, now in that project under sr/main/resources/spring I have an xml file which defines my beans, after I added the resources to export the properties this xml file "cannot be found", I get this exception when I run maven build

```
 used by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [spring/my-beans.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring/my-beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring/my-beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

If i remove the resources the exception does not appear, anyone faced this issue before or know what could be the reason behind this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to load the sprig bean xml? Looks like you are missing a / when loading the context. It should be /spring/my-beans.xml